# Modifying IOCTL function call (where is the definition of ioctl) to flip GPIO pins

Tags: linux, intel

I want to know as to where IOCTL is defined. I want to flip the state of a GPIO pin from within the IOCTL function call. I am using Yocto linux.

Answer (score 1):

The `ioctl` requests are defined per driver. For the new [chardev GPIO](https://www.beyondlogic.org/an-introduction-to-chardev-gpio-and-libgpiod-on-the-raspberry-pi/) this is defined in [`<linux/gpio.h>`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/gpio.h).

The logic these values are encoded is in [`<asm/ioctl.h>`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/ioctl.h). Please note, that this is platform dependent (e.g. MIPS is different than x86 and x86_64).

If you are interested, here is the logic ported to rust: https://docs.rs/nix/0.11.0/src/nix/sys/ioctl/linux.rs.html

However in practice you shouldn't need to convert these request codes on your own. You would just include `<linux/gpio.h>` and then you can use the defined IOCTL request codes like `GPIOHANDLE_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL`. Here are some example implementations: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/gpio

Answer (score 0):

`ioctl` is a c-language kernel function declared in `<sys/ioctl.h>`. See the [linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html).

Here's a copy of the upper portion:

> NAME
>
> ```
>    ioctl - control device
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
>
>    int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long request, ...);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    The ioctl() function manipulates the underlying device parameters of
>    special files.  In particular, many operating characteristics of
>    character special files (e.g., terminals) may be controlled with
>    ioctl() requests.  The argument fd must be an open file descriptor.
>
>    The second argument is a device-dependent request code.  The third
>    argument is an untyped pointer to memory.  It's traditionally char
>    *argp (from the days before void * was valid C), and will be so named
>    for this discussion.
>
>    An ioctl() request has encoded in it whether the argument is an in
>    parameter or out parameter, and the size of the argument argp in
>    bytes.  Macros and defines used in specifying an ioctl() request are
>    located in the file <sys/ioctl.h>.
> ```

Comment: But where is the IOCTL function defined (I am not asking for the declaration). Some one told me that it is driver specific and operates between user and kernel space.

Comment: @SriranjanRasakatla : That's correct. What an `ioctl` does depends on what device (or, rather, what driver) serves the requests of the `fd` that it operates on.